# Six cities. What's the missing number?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, letters

Six cities are listed below. For five of them, their numerical value is given. Find the missing number.

$$\text{London = 6800}$$
$$\text{Paris = 9248}$$
$$\text{Seoul = 9100}$$
$$\text{Tokyo = 7500}$$
$$\text{Istanbul = 1520}$$
$$\text{Jerusalem = ????}$$

Hint #1:

> You may need a calculator.

Hint #2:

> $\text{New York = 2500}$

Hint #3:

> $Times \text{ Square = 1000}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> $\text{J=10, E=5, R=18, U=21, S=19, A=1, L=12, E=5, M=13}$
>  $10 \cdot 5 \cdot 18 \cdot 21 \cdot 19 \cdot 1 \cdot 12 \cdot 5 \cdot 13=280098000 \Rightarrow 8000$
>  **Every number is the last 4 digits of the letters converted into numbers multiplied together.**

Comment: That is correct!